# Create ValueExpression with acces to #{cc}

Tags: jsf, composite-component, wildfly, mojarra

I'm trying to dynamically add a hidden input field to my composite component. The problem is that I somehow can not access the property of my backing facescomponent with the value expression.
Example:

```
public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
  HtmlInputHidden someInput = new HtmlInputHidden();
  someInput.setValueExpression("value", createValueExpression("#{cc ne null}", String.class));  //this will be rendered to <input type="hidden" value="false"/>
  ...
}
```

When I use a CDI-Managed-Bean in the value-expression this works.
When I add an inputfield with access to #{cc} by using xhtml this also works (e.g. input type="hidden" value="#{cc ne null}"/> will render to input type="hidden" value="true"/>).
Is this a bug or am I missing something? I'm using wildfly 8 with mojarra-2.2.6.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's `createValueExpression()`? Own method, derrived method..?

Comment: something like this:

FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory()
            .createValueExpression(context.getELContext(), exp, WHATEVER.class).getValue(context.getELContext());